# I am trying an async ajax call in MVC. The daata is not sent to server

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

The function sends data to server. The billItem stores the detail level entitity data. I am using MVC and i have Create method in controller class HomeController. I have two classes Bill and BillItem that is master and detail respectivelly.

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
                var isValidItem = true;
                if ($('#BillNo').val() == 0) {
                    isValidItem = false;
                    $('#BillNo').siblings('span.error').css('visibility', 'visible');
                }
                else {
                    $('#BillNo').siblings('span.error').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                }
                if ($('#CustomerName').val() == '') {
                    isValidItem = false;
                    $('#CustomerName').siblings('span.error').css('visibility', 'visible');
                }
                else {
                    $('#CustomerName').siblings('span.error').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                }
                if ($('#Address').val() == '') {
                    isValidItem = false;
                    $('#Address').siblings('span.error').css('visibility', 'visible');
                }
                else {
                    $('#Address').siblings('span.error').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                }

                if (isValidItem) {
                    alert(billItem);
                     var data = {
                        BillNo: $('#txtBillNo').val(),
                        CustomerName: $('#txtCustomerName').val(),
                        Address: $('#txtAddress').val(),
                        Gender: $('input[name="Gender"]:checked').val(),
                        BillDetail: billItem
                    }
                    //$(this).val() = "Please wait...";
                    $ajax({
                        url: '/Home/Create',
                        type: "POST",
                        data: JSON.stringify(data),
                        dataType: "JSON",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        success: function (d) {
                            if (d.status == true) {
                                alert("Successfully saved.");
                                billItem = [];
                                $('#txtBillNo').val('');
                                $('#txtCustomerName').val('');
                                $('#txtAddress').val('');
                            }
                            else {
                                alert("Error saving data.");
                            }
                            $('#submit').val('Save');
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("Error saving data.");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: Look at the network tab of your browser's dev tools to inspect the http request send, such as the full URL. Try to replicate it in another program such as Insomnia or Postman. Place breakpoints in your c# application to see if your endpoint is being ran, or look at the console output with logging set to Debug to see how your c# app is routing your request.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Ajax` call should look like this:

```
if (isValidItem) {
    alert(billItem);
    
     var data = {
        BillNo: $('#txtBillNo').val(),
        CustomerName: $('#txtCustomerName').val(),
        Address: $('#txtAddress').val(),
        Gender: $('input[name="Gender"]:checked').val(),
        BillDetail: billItem
    }
    
    //$(this).val() = "Please wait...";
    $ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("Create", "Home")",
        type: "POST",
        data: {"json": JSON.stringify(data)},
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (d) {
            if (d.status == true) {
                alert("Successfully saved.");
                billItem = [];
                $('#txtBillNo').val('');
                $('#txtCustomerName').val('');
                $('#txtAddress').val('');
            }
            else {
                alert("Error saving data.");
            }
            $('#submit').val('Save');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error saving data.");
        }
    });
}
```

And your `Controller` method will get the data like this:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(string json)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    dynamic jsondata = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));

    //Get your variables here from AJAX call
    var BillNo = Convert.ToString(jsondata["BillNo"]);
    var CustomerName = Convert.ToString(jsondata["CustomerName"]);
    var Gender = Convert.ToString(jsondata["Gender"]);
    //Your logic
          
    return Json(new {status="true", msg= "Successful"});
}
```